# "dvipng: not found" when creating matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I try to plot a frequency histogram with matplotlib but it doesn t work and i don t know where is the problem...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

data = np.array([58.35, 71.83, 49.25, 38.89, 12.6, 58.34, 34.5, 11.6, 64.66, \
89.14, 101.84, 26.91, 38.74, 65.03, 35.23, 70.73, 54.52, 73.36, 74.35, \
60.54, 73.52, 24.58, 50.31, 55.63, 14.6, 53.64, 81.6])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

n, bins, patches=ax.hist(data, 10, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: ('%.2f')%(y*1e-3)))
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency (000s)')

plt.show()
```

A part of the error message :

```
sh: 1: dvipng: not found
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1535, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
```

...

Comment: *"it doesn t work"*...  *What* doesn't work?  Explain the problem.  Do you get an error?  An unexpected result?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanations...It crashs and I get : sh: 1: dvipng: not found Exception in Tkinter callback

Comment: There must be something wrong either with how you're running the code, or how you've installed it. It runs fine for me on Mac OS X using Python 3.4 and matplotlib 1.4.2.

Comment: @user3601754, please edit the whole error message into your question. The exact error will help us to understand your problem and others when trying to find a solution for a similar problem.

Comment: @user3601754 I don't see how it comes to call `dvipng` but if you're on linux you can install `dvipng` in 30" and see if your problem goes away

Comment: I will try when i m go back home. Here i am, the internet isn t very fast..thanks for help

Comment: The reason that it is calling `divpng` is that `usetex` is `True`, which means mpl is trying to use `LaTeX` to render the text on your graph which in turn uses `dvipng` to turn the dvi output of `LaTeX` into a png to be include in the raster output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are having a problem with the renderer or backend. You might want to try a different backend, by adding this at the beginning of your code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('macOsX')
```

For other renderers, see here:
http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 50):

In Ubuntu 14.04 I used this command to solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install dvipng
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, too.

Comment: I don't have sudo permission. what can I do?

Comment: usually you need sudo permission to install something. try sudo -i to become root, after that try apt-get install dvipng

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you have some Latex distr. installed you may also go with:

```sh
 sudo tlmgr install dvipng
```

This is especially helpful for Mac, alternatively you can use ports:

```sh
sudo port install dvipng
```

Comment: With macports, I get an "Error: Port dvipng not found".

Comment: @pfincent interesting, according to this: https://ports.macports.org/port/dvipng/ , it should be available. Maybe try updating the ports `sudo port -v selfupdate`?

Comment: I had just installed macports a few minutes earlier before trying to download dvipng, so I didn't assume that was necessary, but it did indeed fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS add this to your code!

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('macOsX')
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27674084/18145256).